# Passing arguments to a Button click event function

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Form that consists of a Username textbox, a Password textbox and a Login button.
I want to activate the Login button after pressing enter once the password textbox is filled. I do not know how to call the function.

```
private void Login_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

 {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(IntrarePassword.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(IntrareUser.Text))
            return;
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.Username = IntrareUser.Text;
        form2.Show();

    }

    private void IntrarePassword_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
       if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            Login_button_Click();
    }
```

What should be the Login_button_Click parameters be?

Comment: There's an `AcceptButton` property in the `Form`. Assign the login button to it. Then when you press `Enter`, `Click` event of the accept button will raise.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to register on the KeyPress event of the password control, filter the key pressed then update the Enabled property of the button.

Msdn is your friend ^^ : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-handle-keyboard-input-at-the-form-level

EDIT: Misunderstood your question, my bad.
As you don't use the arguments, can pass null/default or extract your code into  a new parameterless method that both event handler can call.

Answer (score 0):

Set the form's AcceptButton as Login_button and it will get clicked on pressing enter key.
Enter this code in the form's Load event:

```
 this.AcceptButton = Login_button;
```

If you want the Login button to get **enabled** after pressing enter key, here's it:

In your form, set Login_button's Enabled property to false from Properties tab.

Change your code to:

```
private void Login_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(IntrarePassword.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(IntrareUser.Text))
        return;
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    form2.Username = IntrareUser.Text;
    form2.Show();
}

private void IntrarePassword_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        Login_button.Enabled = true;
}
```